# Foundation 4 : Responsive background image issues when resizing

Tags: css, background, resize, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I am trying to build a one page website using Foundation with a navbar, 4 background images to separate each of the sections. Using foundation the image resize well but as I am closing down the screen the sections are going further away verticaly revealing the white body background at the bottom of each images.
How I can work this around so that I maintain the proportion of the page from a large browser screen to a smartphone?

Here is an example of Html with the size of each images:

```
   <div id="bg">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1900x1000" alt="">
   </div>
   <div style="background: white">
    <div class="row">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
     tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
     quis nostrud exercitation</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div id="bg1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1900x900" alt="">
   </div>
   <div style="background: #2adefe">
    <div class="row">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
     tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
     quis nostrud exercitation</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div id="bg2">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1900x650" alt="">
   </div>  
   <div style="background: ##683b17">
    <div class="row">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
     tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
     quis nostrud exercitation</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div id="bg3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1900x700" alt="">
   </div>
   <div style="background: black">
    <div class="row">
    </div>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
     tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
     quis nostrud exercitation</p>
    </div>
    <div id="bg4">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/1900x400" alt="">
    </div>
```

and the type of CSS I use for each background image:

```
#bg {
  display: block;
  min-height: 559px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
```

Comment: Hop on jsfiddle.net and create your page, then add the link to your post. The code you're giving us here is incomplete.